# Has Windows 7 Fixed the 255 Character File Path Limit?

Tags: file, windows-7, filesystems

As I understand it, the limitation of 255 characters in a file path is a Windows limitation. What is the reasoning for this? If so, has this been resolved in Windows 7?

In our continuous integration practices, we often have deeply nested project structures and it would be extremely useful to be able to go beyond 255 characters. Right now we are somewhat forced to structure our projects in such a way as to not hit this artificial ceiling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But that 260 includes the null character at the end and the `C:\\` at the beginning, so only 255 characters are usable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was mistaken.  Microsoft often quotes the length as 256, which is what you get when you subtract properly, rather than 260, which is technically the limit.

Comment: This problem enrages me. It is still present in windows 8.1. I can't seem to move my files about, even though SOMEHOW the file was created in the first place. If you find some way to create files with 255+ file path names you can totally mess up someone's windows machine.

Comment: According to Jeremy Kuhne the problem is being worked and may soon have a solution.  See this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZppqEMegCAA

Comment: Question is about Windows 7, but anyway, Windows 10 does have am option to turn on long paths for some applications. For more details check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680647/does-max-path-issue-still-exists-in-windows-10

Answer (score 46, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

This explains that Unicode versions of Windows APIs have higher limits, and how to enable that.

Comment: But a word of warning:  There's a bunch of code (mostly 3rd party system utilities and the like) that doesn't play well with longer paths.  You may have issues with that if you start using longer paths.

Comment: Is this article correct?  I did a simple teste with both Windows Explorer and Windows Command Prompt in Windows 7 and I'm not able to create file paths with over 260 characters.  Has Microsoft not updated these applications to use the Unicode versions of the Windows APIs?

Comment: Unfortunately Windows Explorer on Windows 7 x64 is still subject to this path limit.  This gives the impression that the entire operating system has not overcome this limit, when really it is just Windows Explorer that has not been updated to work with longer paths.  It is possible that a 3rd party file manager using the latest APIs could get around this.  Ultimately whether a program appears to hit the path limit will depend on whether that program uses the newest APIs on Windows.

Comment: It isn't a question of "newer" or "older" APIs.  You only get long path support if you explicitly ask for it, and Explorer doesn't do so, presumably for the obvious reason: compatibility with existing third-party applications.

Comment: -1 - A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 21):

You can get around that limit by using subst if you need to.

Comment: more info here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Or robocopy which is built in to Windows, based on this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865863/how-to-move-folder-files-with-path-names-255-characters-in-windows-8-1?lq=1

Comment: You should demonstrate how and provide a link to relevant documentation. -1

Comment: While I upvoted, I agree an example would be useful:  `subst E: D:\TESTDATA\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1\4B871B~1`   That got me around a path that was 500 chars deep. The reason for the ~1s is the way Explorer formatted the path.

Comment: A similar solution would be using [junctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), either through a [shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) or through [mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) Example: ```mklink /J C:\newdir C:\some\really\long\path\```

Answer (score 14):

Workarounds are not solutions, therefore the answer is **"No".**

Still looking for workarounds, here are possible solutions: http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/Windows_File_Paths_Longer_Than_255_Characters

Comment: Core elements of windows including powershell, windows explorer shell, and cmd utilities like del still can not handle paths that exceed 250 characters, and no workaround fixes the fact that core Microsoft technologies do not handle long paths, as of 2016. The short answer here is until Microsoft gets its collective behinds in gear, there is little we can do.

Answer (score 4):

@Cort3z: if the problem is still present, this hotfix:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362
should solve it (from win7 sp1 to 8.1)

Comment: This is a great solution. Have you had any issues after using it?

Answer (score 1):

From Windows 10 version 1607, the limitation has been removed by setting a registry key

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#maxpath

Comment: but not in windows 7 ?

Comment: It doesn't seem reasonable to actually downvote this, because although it doesn't answer the question, it is probably useful to many people who have similar questions.

Comment: There are however other questions covering Win10