# WAMP php copy() fail on long path files

Tags: php

I have activate `LongPathsEnabled` on windows 10 entreprise 
with regedit on 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` = 1
And also on `Local Group Policy Editor` -> `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable win32 long paths`

When I try to copy a very large path file (aprox 300 - 400 characters) with php

```
copy($source, $destination)
```

I get this error:

> failed to open stream: Invalid argument ....

But if I use

```
exec("copy $source $destination");
```

This work correctly

The php `copy()` can be solved by using `exec()` but I need also to use `file_get_contents()` in my work and this thrown the same error

I am very confused if is realy enabled the `LongPathsEnabled` on windows ... or is a php issue.

If is not enabled then why with command line `copy` work?

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure what PHP version you are using but check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28407644/2191572

Comment: I have PHP Version 7.0.0 ...  I have take a look at your suggested answer and someone say: **Starting with PHP 7.1 long and UTF-8 paths on Windows are supported directly in the core** https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880925/2951051 ... I will be try to change php version. Thank's

Comment: No problem and good luck! Definitely let me know your findings

Comment: Try prefixing the paths with "\\?\". This way it should work for paths up to around 1023 characters, even without enabling long paths.

Comment: @axiac I have tried `$destination = "\\?\C:/folder/large_path/large_file"` but still same error when I try `file_get_contents($destination)`

Comment: My previous comment is misleading to some extent. The idea is to put two backslashes, one question mark and another backslash in front of the file name. As PHP string, it should be something like `"\\\\?\\"`.

Comment: Still not working: I have played with `"\\?\\"`  `"\\\?\\"` `"\\\\?\\"`  `"\\\\?\\\\"` neither work

Comment: In change I can confirm @MonkeyZeus suggestion work I have changed php to 7.2.4 And work .... Buuut :(  ... I have other issue .. can't find `php_ssh2.dll` for php7.2.4 .... only for 7.0 .... Buahhhhhh

Comment: You can manually download `php_ssh2.dll` from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/ but it looks like the latest version is only for PHP 7.1 so you can try using PHP 7.1.x on your server and install the dll manually. Make sure to download the proper x86 or x64 version and since you are using Apache make sure you get the "thread-safe" dll with `-ts-` in the file name.

Comment: @axiac ... I have take a look about `"\\?\"` ... this is for command line ... I think never that work with php (except if we use with `exec()` or `system()`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Unfortunately not work. That get error  `Entry Point Not Found` ... `the procedure entry point libssh2_scp_recv2 could not be located in the dynamic link library ... C:\wamp64\bin\php7.1.16\ext\php_curl.dll` ... I have download the right file for my environement `php_ssh2-1.1.2-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip` . Thank you for triyng to help

Comment: You may need to download and install the [VC14 C++ redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: I have yet VC14 C++ installed when I have installed WAMP server (the older php_ssh2 for php 7.0.0 also need and working good in php7.0.0)

Comment: For the moment I have changed name of files before I have sha2 filename and now I changed it to md5 ... Now I have paths with 230-240 characters ( I hope there are no collisions until the new version of the extension comes out :) )

Comment: Relatedly I notice that ZipArchive built into PHP 7.2 is also not long path aware on Windows 10 21h1.