# How to move folder/files with path names > 255 characters in Windows 8.1?

Tags: file, copy, windows-8.1, directory, move

## How can you copy/move a folder or file with path name length > 255 on windows?

I have looked around for ages, and the only possible way I have found is to use the `subst` method. I wish I didn't have to mess about with this. I simply want to copy/move a file or directory, `X`, to location `Y`.

I'm fine with making a `.bat` script, or other kinds of scripts to achieve this.

---

PS: this is marked as of topic, which I'm fine with, but it was being done in a programming context.

Comment: I just want to note also that I have checked out all of these answers, none of which works:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065993/has-windows-7-fixed-the-255-character-file-path-limit
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-find-files-whose-path-names-are-too-long-to/4f905800-2cb5-46ae-80be-99e39c01e854
(more to come)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found a good solution!

The savior is

### [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Robocopy supports path names > 256 by default, and even provides a flag that lets you turn **OFF** support for long path names (flag: `/256`).

Example usage of Robocopy:

`robocopy /E C:/path/with/very/long/names/in/it C:/new/path`

Comment: Ohh boy it took me long to figure this out. Way to go windows.

Comment: FYI robocopy is built in on my Windows 7 machine. Wish I had read this before I lost several files!

Answer (score 1):

Not Windows 8 but in Windows 7, 64bit, I have the same problem and I just discovered that while nothing else worked, I was able to cut and paste folders containing files with path names that were too long into a destination folder with a shorter path. That is, in Explorer.exe, I selected a directory that I couldn't delete because some files had path names that were too long, then CTRL-X to cut it and paste it into another explorer window (CTRL-V).