# Nodewebkit - Deploy the application. Resolving long file names

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have made a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179918/nodewebkit-deploy-the-application), in which I planned to describe my progress while solving the challenge about how to deploy the NW application.
I have made good progress, and I believe that thread is now old for a new challenge that I have.

In short, I have NW application that hosts Hapi.js, React.js and Sequelize. I made an installer using [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). And that works like a charm.
New challenge is as follows:
If a user selects a long installation directory such as:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\MyAppName

Depending on the user name, my installation cant be completed. If the "USERNAME" is short, such as "aa" then it will work, how ever having a full name will not, such as "John Smith".

One solution is to force user to install it on c:\myapplicationname, but client doe not like that idea. Requirement is to have it "installable" anywhere on the system.

I have identifed several node modules, that have over 4 level depth (node_module...\node_module...\node_module) and installer stops right there.

How can I overcome this problem? Does anyone have informaiton regarding NW and NPM3 flat file system?

Comment: Is the problem really the length, or is it rather the space in the "John Smith"?

Comment: The length is the problem in the JohnSmith. Even when I remove the space, it is the same.