# keil compiler error - can not open source input file - but file exists

Tags: path, compiler-errors, window

I compiled in Keil 5
using armcc:

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 (build 20)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
```

and I got following error:

```
compiling softdevice_handler.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\components\softdevice\common\softdevice_handler\softdevice_handler.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\components\softdevice\common\softdevice_handler\softdevice_handler.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
```

I was sure that source c file exists. I added it in GUI and I could open it in GUI.

So why compiler complains that file does not exists if file does exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found that issue was [windows 7 path length limit of ~255 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065993/has-windows-7-fixed-the-255-character-file-path-limit).

Combined with keil compiler stupidity. What it does is that it combines 
project path + relative resource path. So for example:

```
project path: projects/projectX/toolchain/keil5/projectX.uvprojx
src path is : projects/projectX/src/a/b/src.c
```

then what is used internally by armcc is:

```
projects/projectX/toolchain/keil5/../../a/b/src.c
```

it adds extra:

```
 /toolchain/keil5/../../
```

So even if src.c is not too deep, it can go over 255 characters when you sum part of project path.

Solution for arm is to go to: `Project->options->C/C++->Misc Controls` and add "`--reduce_paths`". See keil [armcc manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124941061.htm).

Another option is to copy project closer to root folder so maximum project path is reduced.