# Windows 7 Path too long to create file above 260 Characters with .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64, system.io.file, .net-4.6.2

I trying to create file with more than 260 characters of file path with .Net Framework 4.6.2

This is working fine in Windows 10, but not able to create in Windows 7 environment.

I am trying to create file pragmatically using C#.

Can you please help me to find solution that will work for any Windows environment.

Comment: Theoretically you can with workarounds, but its more practical to just stick to the 260 character limit (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath). It's not called a limit for nothing.

Comment: Yeh but It's working fine with .Net framework 4.6.2 in Win 10 Environment.
I have referred this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception(v=vs.110).aspx        
But It's not working in Win 7 Environment

Comment: for any Windows environment, stick to the limit

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066022/2137237

Comment: Hi Markus, I have followed this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx  
 But I need smart way to achieve it in Win 7 Environment

Comment: You could use my [Zeta Long Paths library](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths). ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZetaLongPaths))

Comment: Also in Windows server 2012 R2 OS, this is not working with more than 260 characters file path, It's giving other error i.e. "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException" while creating file with More than 260 characters. Can anyone help me out from this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not support paths longer than 260 characters. Stick to this limit if you can. Unsupported functionality might break in a Windows update.

You can read more about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath
This link also explains the '\\?\' prefix which allows paths up to approximately 32'767 characters (Example: "\\?\D:\very long path"). But I haven't tested '\\?\' with the C# API.

The following links might also be interesting

- [Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton/

Comment: Yes, but the thing will work in Win 10 after upgrading .Net Framework 4.6.2
  In Win 7 also I have upgraded .Net Framework 4.6.2, but it's misbehaving in other way. So, what will be best way to achieve it as we can achieve it after .Net Framework upgrade to 4.6.2

Comment: @Herin Yes 4.6.2 supports long paths as stated in your link about PathTooLongException. But Win7 doesn't. As stated on the same page PathTooLongException is thrown when the operating system returns a PathTooLong error. Don't expect it to work with Win7. That's not a functionality that was inteded to work with Win7. Just be happy if you find a way to get it to work.

Comment: Hey Renklus, This is also not working with Windows server 2012 R2 OS. Can you suggest better way to come out from this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZetaLongPaths](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths) library for older systems and/or frameworks. There are several similar libraries exists, but this one is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my library. Makes me proud! 